# Swift massive file same as massive view controller?

Tags: swift

How did we get from massive view controller in objc to massive swift file and it's okay ?

In objc we tried so hard to slim classes to its own files, and in swift the classes are slim but instead we stuff everything in the same file because of local file visibility.

So what's different than the massive view controller ? There are still plenty of lines in the same source file, how it could mean easier readability?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should instead look for easier testability and separation of concerns. There are a couple of approaches that you could consider MVVM and VIPER. 
Stuffing everything into a single source file should be avoided. 
May be I am missing something in your question. But you should not be putting everything into one file.